# edit java class file JAD

Tags: java, jad

i need to change the access modifier of one constructor in a class file... how do i do it with jad..

thanks all...

raj...

Comment: JAD is a decompiler, not a classfile modification tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with JAD:

1. Decompile the class with JAD
2. Edit it with your favorite editor
3. Save the file
4. Compile it with `javac`

More simple solution:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("fully.qualified.name.of.your.Class");
ctor = c.getConstructor(...argument types here...);
ctor.setAccessible(true);
```

(Your IDE will suggest the type for `ctor` ... otherwise change it)

Now you can invoke the constructor at runtime.

If you really need to modify the byte code, have a look at [the ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Comment: Aaron, it would be so helpul of you, if yu can provide a snippet where i can make the private constructor taking no arguments accessible... i am nt able to get the proper paramater list thanks...

Comment: This article should help to get you started with reflection: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/